# Check time between two times (into the night - next day?)

Tags: php, datetime, time

I'm having to check between specific time to run a certain bit of code, it has to run from 8pm to 3am, whenever I do a time/check it always fails in the regular methods suggested because I believe we go into the morning next day time, is that correct? And if so how would I do this? It seems impossible.

i.e.

```
    $now = new Datetime("now");
    $begintime = new DateTime('18:00');
    $endtime = new DateTime('03:00');
    if($now >= $begintime && $now <= $endtime){
        die('x');
    }
```

will not activate, even though we are between those times?

Comment: Correct my apologies that was a mistake in my writing, but as it's not 8PM yet where I am I am testing it from earlier. - if I remove the endtime check it still works, I believe it has to do with the fact that it goes into the next morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try `!( $now > $endtime && $now < $begintime)` Which is Falsely for same day between `3:00 AM` to `8:00 PM` Or you can remove Falsely `!`, but you have to check from `3:00 AM` to `8:00 PM` and not from `8:00 PM` to `3:00 AM`

```
$now = new Datetime("now");
$begintime = new DateTime('20:00');
$endtime = new DateTime('03:00');
if(!( $now > $endtime && $now < $begintime) ){
    //This will work if Time between 8PM to 3AM
}else{
    //This will work if Time between 3AM to 8PM
}
```

[Check this Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9c73aaa8546fdc4b1d4ec6a28233669ebb7580a3)

Comment: Where it is fails ? which test case you follow ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$today = strtotime("today");
$yesterday = strtotime("Yesterday");
if(date("H"); >= 0 && date("H") <= 3)
{//Means we are dealing with this after midnight but still before 3AM so take yesterday as start time.
$day = date("d", $yesterday);
$month = date("m", $yesterday);
$year = date("Y", $yesterday);
$begintime = mktime(18,0,0,$month, $day, $year);
}
else
{//We are dealing with it after 3 AM so we take today's 6 PM as start time.
$day = date("d", $today);
$month = date("m", $today);
$year = date("Y", $today);
$begintime = mktime(18, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
//Could have taken day+1 but doesn't works at the end of the month or end of the year.
//So just add number of seconds for 9 hours
$endtime = $begintime + 32400;//

$now = time();
if($now >= $begintime && $now <= $endtime){
    die('x');
}
else {
//Run your code that you wanted to run outside this timeframe
}
```

Comment: When you go to the next day then begintime`  will be next day's `6:00 PM` or `8:00 PM ` and next day time slot from `00:01`  to `03:00` will not work. Just dry run and think this is `1:00 AM`  or `2:00 AM`

Comment: Please check the edited version. I was just adding along with fixing month end and year end issues.

Answer (score 0):

The time inherently needs a date portion, otherwise there's no way to know if "18:00" is today, yesterday, or 100 years from now. This is not a limitation of DateTime or any other implementation, it's... how time works. If you inspect the result of new `DateTime('18:00');` it will have defaulted the date portion to the current day.

If you want to produce this timeframe more reliably:

```php
// if you don't explicitly declare the timezone it will use the system timezone
// which is frequently not what you want.
$tz = new DateTimezone('America/Vancouver');
$begin = new DateTime('20:00', $tz);
// 7 hour interval
$span = new DateInterval('PT7H');
$end = clone $begin;
$end->add($span);

var_dump($begin, $end);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-07-03 20:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Vancouver"
}
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-07-04 03:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Vancouver"
}
```

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php